# What is the difference between akpanalyzer and dex2jar?

Tags: android, apk, decompiler, dex2jar

While working on adding obfuscation to an android mobile application, I tried to tests the generated APK and make sure the code is obfuscated. I did that with 2 different tools - [apkanalyzer](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apkanalyzer) and [dex2jar](https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar) (following [this](https://blog.bramp.net/post/2015/08/01/decompile-and-recompile-android-apk/) guide). I used apkanalyzer to get all the classes with the following command:

`apkanalyzer dex packages myapp.apk`

When inspecting the classes names, it was looked like the obfuscation is worked as expected. But when I inspected the results of dex2jar (using JD-Gui), it looks like the obfuscation is not working - all classes names kept.

To make sure proguard is working, I checked - `mapping.txt` and `seeds.txt` created successfully. I also check one class that appeared on `mapping.txt` (and therefore should be obfuscated) - but on JD-Gui it appear with the real name, and not obfuscated.

My question is: why there is a difference between apkanalyzer and dex2jar output? And which tool produce the right output?

Edit:
I tested it on a demo project and wasn't able to reproduce this behavior. This means that something is weird with how our app is configured.

Thanks in advance!

Omer

Answer (score 0):

I tried it again this morning, after closing and opening JD Gui. Now I can see the obfuscated code correctly also on JD Gui, so there is no issue.